# For loop from 1 to max value in file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark and wanted to do a for loop from 1 to maxValue in the file.

```
  def main(args: Array[ String ]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Shortest Path")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val graph = sc.textFile(args(0)).map( line => { val a = line.split(",")
      Graph(a(0).toInt,a(1).toInt,a(2).toInt) } )


    val distance = new ListBuffer[Long]
    distance += 0
    var i = 0

    for (i <- 1 to 100000){
      distance += Int.MaxValue
    }
```

Here Instead of 100000 I want to put the maximum value out of j and i tuple of the graph.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? And: 1. is every line in the file a `Graph` object? 2. `graph` RDD will be empty, because there's no action (`map` is a transformation)

Comment: yes we can a map transformation on graph as:    val graphset = graph.map(graph => (graph.i, graph.d, graph.j)). Now I want to do a for loop from 1 to (max of i tuple and j tuple) instead of 1 to 100000. where 100k is taken as an arbitrary value by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
val iMax = graph.map{ g => g.i }.max
val jMax = graph.map{ g => g.j }.max

val theMax = math.max(iMax,jMax)
```

Alternatively, you could determine iMax and jMax using one pass over the data with `reduce` or `fold`

Comment: this is so simple, but I am new to scala syntax so I was getting confused :)